# Script won't work, sound doesn't play, and brick doesn't change colour

Tags: lua, roblox

I was making a horror game with my friend on Studio, when suddenly, I go around this problem. I want to make it so the windows change colour to white, play  a lighting sound, and go back to normal, wait 15/20 seconds and loop.

I already put the sound in the script's children, but it doesn't work. I've been trying for a long time now.

```
        script.Parent.BrickColor=("Institutional White")
        script.Sound:Play()
        wait(0.2)
        script.Parent.BrickColor = Dark stone grey
        wait(10)
        loop
    end
```

Expected "=", got "end"

Comment: Is this your full code? What's your expected result? Your code is syntactically wrong. The error message means, lua is waiting for a assignment of `loop`, for instance `loop = 123`. But the expected `=` is missing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are using Roblox Studio for this.

You're on the right track, but there's just a few syntax errors that need to be fixed. When setting a BrickColor to a part, you have to create a new BrickColor object. You can do this using the .new() function.

```
script.Parent.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Institutional White")
```

Next, we need to fix your while loop. Right now, you have the `end` word declared, but you need the `while` statement too! I'm assuming you want the loop to run infinitely. In this case, you can do this:

```
while (true) do
    --Write your code here
end
```

Another thing you have to worry about is your assets loading. To put it simply, an asset is just an object in your game, like a sound, picture, a part, anything really. Sometimes, when you boot up your game, your code will run faster than your assets load. In this case, we need to write code that will wait for the assets to load using the :WaitForChild() function.

```
local part = script.Parent:WaitForChild("MyPart")
local sound = script.Parent:WaitForChild("MySound")
```

Also, another thing with sounds in Roblox Studio. The source of the sound, or where it is played from, depends on what the sound's parent element is. For example, if I put the sound inside `myPart`, the sound will play from the brick itself and get more quiet as you walk away. If you put the sound in a service or a non-physical object instead, like `Workspace` or `script`, then the sound will play globally, and everyone will hear the sound at the same volume.

So, in final, here's what your code should look like:

```
local part = script.Parent
local sound = script:WaitForChild("Sound")

while (true) do
    part.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Institutional White")
    sound:Play()
    wait(0.2)
    part.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Medium stone grey")
    wait(10)
end
```

Hope this helps!